# Import .CSV values to SQL Server 2008 using MFC Application

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, visual-c++, mfc

I have created dialog based application in MFC from here i am connecting the database SQL Server 2008.

up to now coonection was ok.

here i have the .CSV file for inserting large amount of data.How can i insert the values using MFC application with .CSV file in to SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the CSV (Comma Separated Values)  file Character by Character, whenever you encounter a **','** you can take it as on field and on a line break it will be end of record.

Please see [This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53759/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-MFC) for the detailed code.

Then you have simultaneously write into the database table, whenever you encounter the End of Record.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z5139kz6(v=VS.80).aspx#_core_adding_a_record_to_a_recordset) or [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20466933/MFC-using-ODBC-Adding-data-into-database.html) provides a description on how to insert data into the database table using MFC.

Hopefully these will get you started.